# Angular 2 this loses scope when called from external function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a scenario in Angular 2 where I have an exposed method within "ComponentOne's" Class being called by "ComponentTwo".

When "ComponentOne"'s method is called internally, any variables changed within the class (OnInit, AfterInit) show the current value.

however when "ComponentOne"'s method is called from an externally class (ComponentTwo), the "this" does not reference the correct value.

Below is an example

*ComponentOne*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'testa',
  template:`<button (click)="test_method()">CALL DIRECT</button>`
})

export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
 myTest = 5;

constructor(
      private testService: testService
    ) { }

 public test_method = () => {
    console.log(this.myTest);  // when called direct, this value shows "8", but when called from external Component this value shows "5" ???????
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.myTest = 7;
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.myTest = 8;   
 }


}
```

*ComponentTwo*

```
@Component({
      selector: 'testb',
      template:`<button (click)="b_method()">CALL</button>`
    })

export class TwoComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
      private testService: testService
    ) { }

    b_method = () => {
    let x = this.OneComponent.test_method();
    }

}
```

I believe that the issue has to do with Scoped "this", and insuring proper that method uses local scope.

To sum it all up, I want to insure that test_method will always write the same value to the console no matter where it is called from.

Comment: Outside the fact that calling one component from another is a bad habit, ngViewInit, as the name says is an Hook called after the view is initialized.In your example you are using OneComponent(I don't know how do you can use it based on your code) you don't initialize the view so you don't change the value of myTest

Comment: btw what are you trying to achive?

Comment: Does this code compile without errors?

Comment: code compiles without error (I will put an actual example in jsfiddle soon, this is just sudo code).

Comment: I am simply attempting to make a call to a method in ComponentOne.  
Even if I called from ComponentTwo Template:
`<button (click)="ComponentOne.test_method()"></button>`
this.myTest still uses the initial set value of myTest = 5

My goal is to make sure that when I call the method in ComponentOne, it gets the "current" value of myTest  (just like when I call it directly) will update post with more simple summary